# Looking up relative dates from Django DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

**model:**

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

**sql:**

```
SELECT car FROM cars_myclass WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

So, I have something like:

```
cars = MyClass.objects.all().filter(date < ... )
```

But how to write `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object (substracted by [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 29, 21, 54, 30, 836000)
>>> now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 28, 21, 54, 30, 836000)
```

---

```
import datetime

cars = MyClass.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

---

**UPDATE** Comment by Mikko Ohtamaa:

Also to avoid problems with timezones I recommend using [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` (available since Django 1.4)

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

cars = MyClass.objects.filter(date__lt=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: To avoid problems with timezones I recommend using `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now Discussion https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#interpretation-of-naive-datetime-objects

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer with your comment.